# sed OR regex how to remove everything between round brackets

Tags: regex, sed

Like in the topic I need to I need to replace everything  in the round bracket with a star *. .
I've read a lot about the regex but in this case the round bracket are special 
and  I am getting mad.

I got a text like this one

```
550 OU-001 (BAY0-MC2-F14) Unfortunately messages from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

So should be

```
550 OU-001 (*) Unfortunately messages from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

I've tried this one

```
sed -e 's/\(([)]*\)/*/' file
```

but replace only the open brackets in this way.

```
550 OU-001 *BAY0-MC2-F14) Unfortunately messages from xxx.xxx.xxx.x
```

Can somebody help me and explain me the solutions?

Cheers

Comment: you ask the left hand side to look for : a `(`, followed by any number (0? 1? more?) of `)`  : it does that : it finds a `(` and followed by 0 `)` and it replaces that with a `*`.  You also ask it to put what it finds in the first register `\(....\)` will be put in `\1` ) but you never use that register (of course, as you don't really need what you are trying to replace, as you always want to replace it with : `(*)`). So : use `'s/([^)]*)/(*)/'`  instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed 's/([^)]*)/(*)/g'
```

Comment: this would eat all text until the last closing ) on a line

Comment: @PeerStritzinger: You're right but my other suggested sed command `sed 's/([^)]*)/(*)/g'` should work.

Comment: Sure, This regex matches left bracket then text until right bracket and then right bracket and replaces with literal `(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

does this help?

```
sed 's/([^)]*/(*/g' file
```

with your input

```
kent$  echo "550 OU-001 (BAY0-MC2-F14) Unfortunately messages from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"|sed  's/([^)]*/(*/g'
550 OU-001 (*) Unfortunately messages from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `sed` command-:

```
 sed 's/(.*)/(\*)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This sed works:

```
sed 's/([^)]*)/(*)/g
```

It transforms

```
foo (bar) baz (foobar) end
```

to

```
foo (*) baz (*) end
```